# Payload error for windows store application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I have linked two of my projects in which CalendarControl is dependent on NotesApp through a reference but when i compile my project i face 2 errors. Can anyone guide me in the right direction ??

Error   1

Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'App.xaml'. Source files: 
D:\windows store app\Notes\Source\C#\NotesApp\bin\Debug\App.xaml
D:\windows store app\CalendarControl\CalendarControl\CalendarControl\bin\Debug\App.xaml NotesApp

Error   2

Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Common\StandardStyles.xaml'. Source files: 
D:\windows store app\Notes\Source\C#\NotesApp\bin\Debug\Common\StandardStyles.xaml
D:\windows store app\CalendarControl\CalendarControl\CalendarControl\bin\Debug\Common\StandardStyles.xaml   NotesApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround this, go to the DLL output folder (e.g. bin\Release), create a new folder named like your DLL-Name (e.g. MyUserControlLibrary) and move the XAML files down to this folder.

bin\Release

MyUserControlLibrary.dll

MyUserControlLibrary.pri

\MyUserControlLibrary [folder] <-- create

```
   UserControl1.xaml <-- move here

   UserControl2.xaml <-- move here
```

Comment: I have the same error just with music files: Error 4 Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'ambient_2_adpc.wav'. Source files: 
C:\Users\johann\Desktop\StoneGaard\XAudioPlayer\ambient_2_adpc.wav
C:\Users\johann\Desktop\StoneGaard\ARM\Release\XAudioPlayer\ambient_2_adpc.wav MVVMTestApp, But I cannot get your solution to work, do you have any proposal? If so I can create a question so you can get points?